# Include db access in my middleware.js file

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I need to add a new duplicate email control process in my middleware.js file.
This is my **middleware.js** node file :

```
module.exports = {
    requiresLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.session.loggedIn) {
            console.log(" FORBIDDEN CAUSE YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN  ")
            res.status(403).send({
                errorCode: "403"
            })
            return
        } else {
            next() // continue the process
        }
    },
    permission_valid(permission) {
        return function(req, res, next) {
            if (!req.session.user.permissions.includes(permission)) {
                console.log(" FORBIDDEN CAUSE THE PERMISSION IS MISSING ")
                res.status(403).send({
                    errorCode: "403"
                })
                return
            } else {
                next() // continue the process
            }
        }
    },
    duplicate_email(db, email) {

        db.collection("users").findOne({
            'email': email
        }, function(findErr, result) {
            if (!result) {
                //  next() // continue the process
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**duplicate_email()** is not working cause I have **no db.collection access** in my middleware.js file, I have tried async await, I have tried plenty of things.

I have tried out to change my middleware to this format :

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
    function requiresLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.session.loggedIn) {
            console.log(" FORBIDDEN CAUSE YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN  ")
            res.status(403).send({
                errorCode: "403"
            })
            return
        } else {
            next() // continue the process
        }
    }
}
```

But as long as I do that, **requiresLoggedIn(req, res, next)** and **permission_valid(permission)** won't work any more in the web services, don't know why:

This is one of my working web services, how could I add the eMail duplicate control  middleware to them , please? :

```
  app.post("/createUser", middleware.requiresLoggedIn, middleware.permission_valid("CREATE_USER"), function(req, res) {
```

This is what I should have, but it doesn't work :

```
  app.post("/createUser", middleware.requiresLoggedIn, middleware.permission_valid("CREATE_USER"),middleware.duplicate_email(db, req.body.email), function(req, res) {
```

I would appreciate if you could help me a few, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved similar issue by attaching the db object on the **base request** which all the requests are inherits from.

```js
import express from 'express';

express.request.db = db;
// ------^ this is the base request which all requests inherits from.
```

Then your `db` will be available in each request by accessing `request.db` in your middleware / controller

Comment: Thank you ! I will try out this theses days!